# R remove rows with condition rows contains negative values

Tags: r, dataframe

How to remove the rows in a dataframe which entire rows values are negative?

```
structure(list(name = c(1,-2,-6), data1 = c(1,-30,6), 
data3 = c(1,-51,-6), score1 = c(0, -40, 10), 
score2 = c(20, -25, 10)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

output

```
name data1 data3 score1 score2
 1     1     1      0     20 
-6     6    -6     10     10
```

Answer (score 2):

Checking the `rowSums` if `x > 0`.

```
DF[rowSums(DF > 0) != 0, ]
#   name data1 data3 score1 score2
# 1    1     1     1      0     20
# 3   -6     6    -6     10     10
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `if_all` and negate (`!`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   filter(!if_all(where(is.numeric), ~ .x < 0))
  name data1 data3 score1 score2
1    1     1     1      0     20
2   -6     6    -6     10     10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if_any` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(if_any(.cols = everything(),.fns = ~. > 0))

  name data1 data3 score1 score2
1    1     1     1      0     20
2   -6     6    -6     10     10
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans i have few string column like name1 and name2, name3 columns accept this column it has to see only a rest column is it possible filter like that

Comment: I did not understand, but it is possible to only apply the criteria to certain columns, change the inpur for `.cols`

Answer (score 1):

To filter out all rows in which all numeric values are negative, we should use `across(where(is.numeric))` inside `if_any`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(if_any(across(where(is.numeric), ~.x >=0))
```